# ternary(if) + filter === value doesn't work in React

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, filter

Why does the `e.target.value === 0` and `e.target.value === 21` not work?
I select `--choose an option--`, it return [], I expect return all id.
I select `≥21`, it return id 19,16,20,21, I expect return id 21, 27,27,30.

but I select 0-10 and 11-20, they work

```
const Test = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      date: '2005',
      id: 27,
    },
    {
      date: '2005',
      id: 27,
    },
    {
      date: '2003',
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      date: '2001',
      id: 19,
    },
    {
      date: '2000',
      id: 4,
    },
    {
      date: '2014',
      id: 30,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 16,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 10,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 20,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 21,
    },
  ];

  const [newId, setNewId] = useState(data);
  const [filter, setFiltered] = useState();

  const handle = (e) => {
    const aa = newId.filter((item) =>
      e.target.value === 0
        ? item.id > 0 //return all id, doesn't work
        : e.target.value === 21
        ? item.id >= 21 //return id >= 21, doesn't work
        : item.id <= e.target.value && item.id > e.target.value - 10
    );
    setFiltered(aa);
    console.log(aa);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <select id="select" onChange={handle}>
        <option value="0">--choose an option--</option>
        <option value="10">0-10</option>
        <option value="20">11-20</option>
        <option value="21">≥21</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You don't have any `if` here, you have a ternary expression. This could be more clearly done with `&&` and `||` or by actually using an `if`/`else`. Breaking it down into `if`/`else` would be *much simpler* to debug.

Comment: @crashmstr sorry, I tried `if/else" they are same result...., I updated the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing using `===` this also checks types and the event is most likelly returning a `String` from `e.target.value`.

If you are expecting `e.target.value` to be a `Number` you could parse it before the filter action.

(I get rid of the ternary because is harder to read.)

```
const aa = newId.filter((item) => {
    const value = +e.target.value; // Now its a number
    if (value === 0) return true; // will filter all
    if (value === 21) return item.id >= 21 //only true if the item is equal or higher than 21
    // Basically any other case
    return item.id <= value  && item.id > value - 10
});
```

Comment: It should be `item.id >= 21`.

Comment: Tnx @xehpuk I didnt notice

Comment: @Woohaik May I ask question here? 
1)why `true` = all?
2)all e.target.value 100% = string, right?

Comment: 1) When you are filtering using `.filter()` the return type should be a boolean, if its true then will add the element to the new filtered array, so a true will always add elements.

Comment: 2) the value will always be a String, even if you explicitly say in the input type=number, you receive a String

Comment: @Woohaik Thank you very much from the bottom of my heart

Answer (score 0):

You have the type if id as integer on your array of objects but you set value as string and again you compare string with integer. Thats why this problem occured.

Please look through this example:

```
const App = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      date: '2005',
      id: 27,
    },
    {
      date: '2005',
      id: 27,
    },
    {
      date: '2003',
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      date: '2001',
      id: 19,
    },
    {
      date: '2000',
      id: 4,
    },
    {
      date: '2014',
      id: 30,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 16,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 10,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 20,
    },
    {
      date: '2011',
      id: 21,
    },
  ];

  const [newId, setNewId] = useState(data);
  const [filter, setFiltered] = useState();

  const handle = (e) => {
    const aa = newId.filter((item) =>
      Number(e.target.value) === 0
        ? item.id > 0 //return all id, doesn't work
        : Number(e.target.value) === 21
          ? item.id >= 21 //return id >= 21, doesn't work
          : item.id <= Number(e.target.value) && item.id > Number(e.target.value) - 10

    );
    setFiltered(aa);
    console.log(aa);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <select id="select" onChange={handle}>
        <option value={0}>--choose an option--</option>
        <option value={10}>0-10</option>
        <option value={20}>11-20</option>
        <option value={21}>≥21</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export { App }
```